# Migration from glassfish to apache

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, glassfish-3

I created a project using Netbeans and selected Glassfish 3.1 as a server, it also uses Derby database. Now I want to migrate to Apache Tomcat 7, I just did the following:

- Stopped Glassfish
- Changed the Netbeans project's properties to use Apache 7 instead of Glassfish
- Added Apache to Netbeans and started it

When I try to build the project, several error messages appear like:

> error: cannot find symbol
>   import javax.persistence.Basic;

although I ensured that /bin path of Java is set correctly in Apache server properties in Netbeans and that src.zip path is also set.

I think there are some steps that must be followed to have a successful migration, can any one guide me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat does not come with the JPA specification. It is a Servlet container only.

You must add JPA specification plus Hibernate (implementation) to your project and make sure it will be deployed on your WEB-INF/lib.

Then, make sure your Persistence Unit is of transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL", and configure all necessary properties to create a connection.

**Example:**

```
  <persistence-unit name="bookmark-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <class>com.sample.domain.YourEntity</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />

         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

Obs: this is an HSQLDB example. Adjust for Derby. ;-)

UPDATE: there's a great tutorial for Tomcat+JPA+EclipseLink [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial).

Comment: Actually, consider adding JPA libraries to your Tomcat installation, as mentioned on the TUtorial that is linked on my answer.